# How to exit the login of wandb?Two people have two accounts on one machine...Anyway other than relogin?

Tags: authentication, exit, conflict, wandb

There are two people using wandb api on one machine. If one forgets to relogin before running, the other one's run will be shown in the prevois one's account. I wonder if there is a way to exit the login state and then the other one will know that he/ she hasn't login before he/her starts running programs. IN A HURRY for help about this.
The senoir students in my lab ask me to try to do so but I simply don't know how and I couldn't find a answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WANDB_API_KEY env var for this.

> Multiple wandb users on shared machines

> If you're using a shared machine and another person is a wandb user, it's easy to make sure your runs are always logged to the proper account. Set the WANDB_API_KEY  environment variable to authenticate. If you source it in your env, when you log in you'll have the right credentials, or you can set the environment variable from your script.
> Run this command export WANDB_API_KEY=X where X is your API key. When you're logged in, you can find your API key at wandb.ai/authorize.

https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/advanced/environment-variables

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! I'll try now!